# Dynamically update combobox list based on API response

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, combobox, vue-component, vuetify.js

[image]

I have a combobox of cities

```
<v-combobox
    v-model="city"
    :items="cities"
    item-text="name"
    label="City"
    v-on:keyup="getCities(city)"
></v-combobox>
```

I'm trying to call the API to as users typing ...

Ex. if user enter `bos`

I will sent `bos` to API and I will back a response back, I would like to update my list.

I can't seem to access `this.city` model value.

---

> ***Note:*** : As soon as I change `v-combobox` to `v-textfield`,
> I can access `this.city` model value. But my goal is to use **combobox**.

Do you spot anything that I miss ?

Comment: Looks like you forget to add `item-value` attribute . Also instead of passing city as a param. You can directly access `this.city` inside `getCities()` method. I will create a working demo by tomorrow for your reference 

Answer (score 1):

Observations/Suggestions **:**

- As per my understanding `cities` is an array of objects. If Yes, You have to use `item-value` to bind the values for the options.
- Your issue is related to the `return-object` property which is apparently true by default. Disabling it causes the `v-combobox` to work as expected.
- Instead of passing `city` inside `getCities` method as a parameter. You can directly access the `v-model` value using `this` keyword.

  ```
  getCities() {
      console.log(this.city);
  }
  ```
- I will suggest you to use `@change` event instead of `@keyup` as user might select the value from the dropdown instead of typing. Hence, `@keyup` will not trigger in that case.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      city: null,
      cities: [{
        name: 'Foo'
      },
      {
        name: 'Bar'
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getCities() {
      console.log(this.city)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.5/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-combobox
            v-model="city"
            :items="cities"
            label="City"
            item-text="name"
            item-value="name"
            @change="getCities"
            :return-object="false"
            outlined
            dense
          ></v-combobox>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```